# How to define dashed lines with arrows in the tikz package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

Good afternoon,

I would like to indicate the directions as I have done for the solid lines but for the dashed lines. How could I do this? I attach an image of how I would like it to look like.

[image]

Thank you.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=1cm and 1cm,
  mynode/.style={draw,circle,text width=0.5cm,align=center}
]

\node[mynode] (z) {A};
\node[mynode,below left=of z] (x) {B};
\node[mynode, below right=of z] (y) {C};

\node[mynode,right=of y] (a) {B};
\node[mynode,above right=of a] (b) {A};
\node[mynode,right=of b] (d) {C};
\node[mynode,below right=of d] (c) {D};

\path (z) edge[dashed] (x)
(z) edge[dashed] (y);

\path (b) edge[dashed] (d)
(a) edge[dashed] (b)
(d) edge[-latex] (c);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Examples}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: in your case: `edge[dashed, ->]` or `edge[dashed, -latex]`

Comment: Kindly check out the "minimal introduction to tikz" from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf , section "arrows and the like" , and look up details in the (huge) pgf manual. // Next time please include all required preambles, `\begin{document` until `\end{document}` so we can copy and compile your code ;-) Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved by comments.